# How to log with Serilog Sink Http Authentication Bearer

Tags: .net, authentication, serilog

I have a console app that I want to log to Logtail using Serilog (v2.12.0) http sink (v8.0.0) with custom httpclient configured for authentication bearer like below:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.Http;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        ILogger Log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .MinimumLevel.Information()
                        .WriteTo.Http(
                            requestUri: "https://in.logtail.com/",
                            queueLimitBytes: null,
                            httpClient: new CustomHttpClient()
                        )
                        .CreateLogger()
                        .ForContext<Program>();
        
        Log.Information("log message in json format");
    }
}

public class CustomHttpClient : IHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public CustomHttpClient() => httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public void Configure(IConfiguration configuration) =>
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "bearer token");

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, Stream contentStream)
    {
        var content = new StreamContent(contentStream);
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var response = await httpClient
            .PostAsync(requestUri, content)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        return response;
    }

    public void Dispose() => httpClient?.Dispose();
}
```

So far it's not working but if I use the log message in json format in Postman it works.
Here are the instruction for http source from Logtail:

1. Initialize a new POST HTTP request in your programming language of choice
2. Serialize a single log object or an array of your logs into JSON or MessagePack and use it as the request body
3. Set the Content-Type header to application/json or application/msgpack
4. Set the Authorization header to Bearer "my bearer token"
5. Send the request to https://in.logtail.com/
6. Wait for a 202 response

Comment: Add a Console.ReadLine() at the end of the main method to wait for the logging to occur, one common pitfall is that the main execution terminates the application before the actual logging happens.

Comment: It's doesn't work

Comment: Does your method PostAsync get called if you set a breakpoint inside it?

Comment: I don't think it did. I wanted to use Serilog with Logtail but Logtail doesn't have support for Serilog, only NLog. But Serilog has http sink and I used that. The custom http client above is from the sample of Serilog.sinks.http but for simple authorization, I modified it for token bearer. I guess I should ditch Serilog and create http client to send log directly to Logtail, instead of going through Serilog.

Comment: I would first test that CustomHttpClient works standalone against logtail (without Serilog), does that work?

Answer (score 0):

content should be structured to match the requirements of the POST event for your specific URL. *https://in.logtail.com/*.

//sample
var content = new StreamContent(contentStream);

var jsonData = new StreamReader(contentStream).ReadToEnd();

// Example: To check use the same data which you are posting for postman

var newJson = // The JSON data should be structured to match the requirements of the POST event for your specific URL.

var content1 = new StringContent(newJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await httpClient
.PostAsync(requestUri, content1)
.ConfigureAwait(false);

return response;

This should work

Comment: Also please dispose the logger